# displaying page content in Stylish pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have created  button with pupup window.

In popup I want to display some content having two text area and two buttons. I added the code but content in popup window appears misaligned.

Rather appearing in the middle of popup window.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/d4qtj/3/

```
<div class= "c1">
    <div class="row demo-row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="signup" href="#signup" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Mention this month</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4qtj/18/)**

I hope, Here is a absolute solution for your query

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d4qtj/18/show/)**

```
    <div id="signup">

        </div>
```

I have aligned `width` and `margin` in between the `DIV` signup

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, u want your button to be in the middle of your page?

Try using `allign-center: auto;` in your stylesheet.

Comment: not only button, but the content which apear in popup box, that I want to align

Comment: Try using `text-allign: center;` then.

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer so we know you don't need anymore help with this question.